# Python with MongoEngine - access to the list of custom model attributes

Tags: python, mongodb, inheritance, copy

Looking for easy access to the list of custom model attributes in some Python model classes I have. I'm using MongoEngine as my ORM, but the question is a general inheritance and OOP.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to access custom model attributes from a method in a Mixin class that I'll inherit from in all of my model classes.

Consider the following class structure:

```
class ModelMixin(object):
    def get_copy(self):
        """
        I'd like this to return a model object with only the custom fields
        copied.  For the City object below, it would run code equivalent to:

          city_copy = City()
          city_copy.name = self.name
          city_copy.state = self.state
          city_copy.popluation = self.population
          return city_copy

        """


class City(BaseModel, ModelMixin):
    name = orm_library.StringField()
    state = orm_library.StringField()
    population = orm_library.IntField()
```

This would allow the following:

```
>>> new_york = City(name="New York", state="NY", population="13000000")
>>> new_york_copy = new_york.get_copy()
```

But, it has to work for *arbitrary* models.  Somehow, it has to determine what custom attributes have been defined in the subclass, instantiate an instance of that subclass, and copy over only those custom properties, *without copying the builtin attributes and methods from the parent BaseModel class (which has a ton of random stuf in it I'm not concerned with*.

Anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: It looks like you want get all the `Instance Variables` from the object and not `custom attributes` of the class, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  As to the wording, this is from the python docs: "data attributes correspond to “instance variables” in Smalltalk, and to “data members” in C++."  So I think we are talking about the same thing, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have several tools at your disposal to pull this off
(and if the code I have below doesn't quite do what you want, you should
be able to adapt it pretty readily). Namely:

- the `__class__` attribute will give you the class of an object
- the `vars()` function will enumerate the attributes of an object (or class)
- the `setattr()` and `getattr()` functions can let you manipulate
  an arbitrary attribute by name.
- to distinguish which class attributes are interesting to you
  (in your case, those that are MonogEngine fields) I check the
  class type of the model attribute itself; [quick glance of MongoEngine
  sources seems to indicate that you'll want to change that to 'BaseField'](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/fields.py#L41)

---

```
class ModelMixin(object):
    def get_copy(self):

        # Get the class for the 

        C = self.__class__

        # make a new copy

        result = C()

        # iterate over all the class attributes of C
        # that are instances of BaseField

        for attr in [k for k,v in vars(C).items() if v.__class__ == BaseField]:
            setattr(result, attr, getattr(self, attr))

        return result
```

To test the above (creating dummy classes for MongoEngine models/fields)

```
class BaseField(object):
    pass

class BaseModel(object):
    baseField = BaseField()

class City(BaseModel, ModelMixin):
    x = BaseField()
    y = BaseField()

c = City()
c.x = 3
c.y = 4
c.baseField = 5

d = c.get_copy()
print d.x # prints '3'
print d.y # prints '4'
print d.baseField # correctly prints main.BaseField, because it's not set for d
```